# Solving $\sin$($x$ - $\frac{π}{5}$) - $\cos$($\frac{π}{10}$) = 0.

Tags: trigonometry

Find all the **exact angles** between $0$ and $π$, which satisfy the equation
$\sin(x - \frac{π}{5}) - \cos(\frac{π}{10}) = 0$.

I have tried using the sum and difference formula for the $\sin$ function, but I'm still stuck after that. Dividing throughout by $\cos$ seems out of question as well.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use  $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2-A\right)=\cos A$

and $\sin x=\sin B\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^nB$ where $n$ is any integer

OR $\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-C\right)=\sin C$

and $\cos x=\cos D,x=2m\pi\pm D$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 2):

$$sin(x-\frac\pi5)=cos(\frac\pi{10})$$
$$sin(x-\frac\pi5)=sin(\frac\pi{2}-\frac\pi{10})=sin(\frac{2\pi}{5})$$
$$x-\frac\pi5=\frac{2\pi}{5}\pm2n\pi$$
Given $0<x<\pi$, $x=\frac{3\pi}{5}$

Comment: There is another solution.  Remember that $\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\theta$.